# Usar modelo multi-tenancy ou outros tipos?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, arquitetura-de-software

Estou trabalhando em vários sistemas para uma única empresa. Em alguns casos, os sistemas devem se integrar e em outros não. Por exemplo, o controle de acesso de usuários, deve se comunicar com todos os demais sistemas, já que é assim que se define que usuário ira acessar determinados recursos. Outro caso, o sistema de  compras (insumos, material de escritório etc), deve se comunicar com o sistema de estoque, mas o de agendamento para atendimento de clientes não deve ter relação com  o de compras nem de estoque.

Como estruturar meu Banco de dados diante desse cenário? Com uma única Base, dividida em tabelas e relacionadas, ou em varias bases cada uma com as tabelas de seu escopo?

Trabalho com uma aplicação web, utilizo JPA, Hibernate no *back-end*, e no *front* estou com AngularJS. O banco é MySQL. Acredito que terei no máximo uns **35 usuários** pendurados simultaneamente e tenho um servidor simples, um i5 com 8gb e até posso solicitar alguns upgrades.

Hoje já tenho alguns sistemas legados aqui e eles estão em varias bases, mas a ideia é extingui-los. Também é bom saber que as rotinas de backup se tornam bem complicadas aqui, pelo menos nessa versão do MySQL 5.7.21, o esquema de *backups* e *restore* pelo Workbench não funciona. Dá um monte de pau e não finaliza os *restores*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do jeito que achar melhor. Não temos como saber o que é melhor sem saber cada detalhe, e principalmente como poderá acontecer no futuro. A tecnologia que usa ou a quantidade de usuários, de forma geral, pouco importa.

Nem sei se a descrição está correta, porque é muito difícil alguém dizer quantos usuários simultâneos terá sem botar o sistema para rodar. Quase sempre tem bem menos do que a pessoa imagina, ou seja, simultâneo de verdade costuma ter 2, 3 ou 4, mas se for muitos, então não dá pra ser muito preciso, dá para falar em 50, em 100, números redondos. Simultaneidade não é o que você acha que é. Por isso as pessoas acham que precisam de uma arquitetura muito mais complexa do que realmente precisa.

O que está falando nada tem a ver com *multi-tenancy*, o motivo principal de eu ter respondido. Esse conceito é o oposto do que está descrevendo, é quando o sistema deve se adaptar para rodar para vários clientes diferentes.

A questão do *backup* não tem relação com isso. É outro problema e não é por causa do modelo em si e sim pela maneira como ele está sendo feito e como foi configurado.

Estar tudo junto ou não, nada tem a ver com a performance em qualquer *engine* do MySQL. Outras decisões é que fazem a performance ser boa ou ruim. Pode influenciar um mínimo, mas nada que faça real diferença.

É claro que cada modelo adotado trará vantagens e desvantagens e tem que colocar na balança cada um. Um deles fará você ter mais dificuldade com algumas operações e outro modelo terá com outras operações, não existe nada livre de desvantagens.

Eu prefiro sempre que possível em um banco de dados relacional colocar tudo na mesma base, vejo pouca ou nenhuma vantagem em separar. Tem que veja, mas eu obviamente discordo delas. Sempre que tem relação, precisa de transação entre tabelas, se não estiver na mesma base vira um martírio, e se não tem algo assim no seu cenário hoje, um dia pode vir a ter. Quase sempre é difícil justificar a motivação para separar, até porque ela dá tanto trabalho em aplicações mais complexas que não vale o esforço, e nas simples tanto faz, até que ela deixe de ser simples.

Imagina ter que ficar pensando em separar algumas coisas e juntar outras. O caso dos usuários do seu exemplo. Se ele deve se integrar com tudo ou faz separado e se vira para integrar com tudo (este caso pode ser simples, nem todos são) ou então coloca junto. Mas como colocar junto se tem partes separadas? Replicando? Fica horrível, perto do inviável. E se o que funcionava bem separado um dia muda e precisa estar junto?

Esse site é um dos 50 mais acessados do mundo e tem tudo junto, roda de forma extremamente simples e com performance absurdamente boa. A não ser que você trabalhe no Facebook, Netflix, essas empresas, não vejo como o separado seja uma boa ideia. Mas a moda atual do mercado é separar (tenho palestra mostrando como isso é mais problemático do que as pessoas pensam).

Mas eu costumo dizer que se não souber bem o que está fazendo, se não entender os fundamentos, não dominar cada detalhe da tecnologia que está usando, nada adianta tomar uma decisão de arquitetura, todas as arquiteturas darão errado, o problema não está nesse ponto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então, eu tenho esse pensamento, tudo na mesma base organizando tabelas, procs etc pela nomenclatura. Agora, esse negocio de moda me deixa desconfiado. Você disse que tem palestras sobre isso, teria algum conteudo para indicar, preciso embasar minha decisão.

Comment: Não muito, é a minha experiência que uso na minha palestra.

Comment: Maniero, era isso que precisava mesmo. Alguns exemplos, casos de sucesso.