# Nomenclatura de tabelas com nome da empresa e sigla de sistema

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, convenções-de-nome

Devo colocar o nome da empresa no início do nome das tabelas?

É uma convenção colocar o nome da empresa, a sigla do sistema, na frente da tabela?

Por exemplo:

Para a tabela de usuários, devo colocar: `playcenter_diversoes_usuarios`

Onde `playcenter` é a empresa, e `diversoes` é o sistema.

O uso de *schemas* de banco de dados seria uma alternativa? Ou pelo fato de haver gerenciadores de bancos de dados limitados (por exemplo Sybase) em que dependendo da versão não há *schemas*, isso pode ser um empecilho?

Colocar o nome da empresa na frente não pode gerar confusão? As grandes empresas fazem muitas fusões.

Dependendo da tecnologia quando usando um dblink, ou algum outro recurso, teríamos problemas ao encontrar tabelas com o mesmo nome em bancos de dados separados?

Comment: Há razão, a pessoa não sabe o que está fazendo, essa é maior razão usada por quase tudo que se faz em TI. Somos amadores remunerados https://www.eximiaco.tech/pt/2019/05/31/somos-amadores-remunerados/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe, se o mesmo banco de dados tiver várias empresas. É um erro de modelagem, é arrumar uma solução para um problema criado por uma decisão errada. Então é melhor usar *schemas* ou mesmo só outra base de dados, dependendo da necessidade (pode ser por limitação do banco de dados usado).

Fusões nada tem a ver com isso porque se eles se fundirem vira uma empresa só, e se forem independentes não terá esse problema, principalmente quais an chances de resolver operar as duas empresas independentes na mesma instância do banco de dados do conglomerado? Isto pode ser útil em sistema [*multitenant*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364129/101) ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/339235/101) e [mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321416/101)), mas acho que é um jeito meio torto, na verdade nem sei se poderia chamar de *multi-tenancy*.

Não é só isto, as pessoas vivem prefixando nomes de tabelas e campos com coisas sem sentido, provavelmente porque modelaram errado.

Usar o nome do sistema não faz muito sentido porque uma tabela pode ser usada em dois sistemas. E se realmente nunca é, então porque está no mesmo `*schema* ou mesmo banco dados? Separe o que é de cada coisa se tem uma barreira tão forte.

Modelar certo provavelmente é a tarefa mais importante de todo software, especialmente se você expõe o modelo como se fosse uma API do sistema, ou seja, o modelo não é só um detalhe de implementação mas sim um contrato do que está fazendo no sistema. Por falhar muito nisso a maioria dos sistemas são ruins de dar manutenção, e não é o monte de técnica que as pessoas aprendem que fará o código melhor em cima de um modelo ruim.

Foi dito que é comum em grandes empresas fazerem isto. Eu nunca vi (não tive acesso à muitas grandes empresas o AP pode ter tido) e parece absolutamente equivocado, uma falta completa de entendimento como funciona um banco de dados, mas não pode falar com tanta propriedade sem um contexto, só acho que se ocorre muito não está importante contexto.

E para complementar de acordo com a recompensa oferecida, não tem política adequada para isto, eu tenho experiência enorme nisso e todos os casos são porque a pessoa não sabe usar o SGDB direito ou a pessoa não tem a menor ideia como se modela este tipo de coisa, isto é estranho porque é errado, simples assim. Está tudo descrito acima como se resolve de forma adequada os cenários descritos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: obrigado @Maniero, e sim irei expor como API. Mas na fusão e se as empresas tinham tabelas com o mesmo nome? A solução é deixar tudo como está, em dois bancos de dados separados certo? Ou fundir com uma nomenclatura nova, já que está alterando toda a estrutura de dados certo?

Comment: Já respondi isso, se elas tiverem tabelas com o mesmo nome não tem problema porque as empresas não devem ser colocadas na mesma base de dados, isso não faz sentido algum, você está falando de uma situação hipotética que você não sabe como funciona, é um caso parecido com o que eu descrevo em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401729/101, não vai acontecer, mas se acontecer não é do jeito que acha que é. Se houver uma fusão de verdade só haverá uma empesa, não haverá duas. E se houver duas, cada uma terá seu banco de dados, não vai mudar nada. Está procurando um problema onde não existe.